# Faster way of validating conditions in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to develop a Python script which handles tens of thousands of number data. In there I have two ways to validate using an "if" condition as seen below.

```
#Script 1
if(condtion_1 and condition_2):
    do_onething()
elif(condition_1 and condition_3):
    do_another()

#Script 2
if(condition_1):
    if(condition_2):
        do_onething()
    elif(condition_3):
        do_another()
```

In the above scripts, is script 2 faster than script 1 when it comes to checking some conditions? If so, as far as I could find, people are telling to avoid nesting. But should I avoid nesting at the cost of performance?

Comment: If `condtion_1` is a variable, not a method call, the difference will be completely negligible.

Comment: Actually I find the 2nd option more readable as it is clear that the condition_1 is checked only once. If nesting becomes an issue you can move some code to another method.

Comment: @matszwecja Depending on the type of the value referenced by `condition_1`, `bool(condition_1)` could be a source of non-negligible overhead.

Comment: Could you provide example data? Maybe there is a way to perform this as numpy operations, which are probably faster

Comment: If you have "tens of thousand numbers", then `numpy` and/or `pandas` are your friends. You'll get access to numerical methods written in C (which we call 'vectorized') from the convenience and beauty of Python. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: @PierreD It should be noted that vectorization is not always proper. Just the other day I had a script froma  colleague that used pandas and was impossible to run because it consumed upwards of 14G of RAM performing in memory joins etc. I modified it to use simple for loops and it run fine using at most 350M of RAM... it also took less time. So throwing libraries at random without looking at the algorithm doesn't generally help, in many cases it might just hide a big issue under the cover